# JoltTransformJSON - Extract attribute witouth remove it

Tags: apache-nifi

first at all, i am kind of newbie with nifi so feel free to change everywhting you see.

I am ussing JoltTransformJSON. My input JSON is the next one:

```
{
"ID": "123",
"Text1": "aaa",
"Text2": "aaa",
"Text3": "aaa"
}
```

And I need the next output:

```
{
"data": {
    "ID": "123",
    "Text1": "aaa",
    "Text2": "aaa",
    "Text3": "aaa"
},
"date": "",
"dataset": "",
"ID": "123"
}
```

The var date and dataset are attributes from the flow, so there is no problem here, **the problem is i need to extract the value of ID, in this case 123 but this is just an example, without deleted the ID inside de field data**. My Jolt Specification is the next one:

```
[{
"operation": "shift",
"spec": {
    "*": "data.&"
}
},{
"operation": "default",
"spec": {
    "dataset": "${dataset:toLower()}",
    "date": "${date}"
}
}]
```

and with that i have all EXCEPT the ID field, that i dont know how to do it :(.

Thankss

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Try with below spec:***

```
[{
  "operation": "shift",
  "spec": {
    "*": "data.&",
    "ID": ["ID", "data.ID"]
  }
}, {
  "operation": "default",
  "spec": {
    "dataset": "${dataset:toLower()}",
    "date": "${date}"
  }
}]
```

***Output:***

```
{
  "ID" : "123",
  "data" : {
    "ID" : "123",
    "Text1" : "aaa",
    "Text2" : "aaa",
    "Text3" : "aaa"
  },
  "date" : "${date}",
  "dataset" : "${dataset:toLower()}"
}
```

Comment: The problem with that spec is that you DELETE the field ID from 'data', and I need the field ID in 'data' and 'outside'(with date and dataset)

Comment: @Carlos, Please check my updated answer, **`"ID": ["ID", "data.ID"]`** this will resolve the issue and keeps `ID` field in default and also in `data` struct.